# Installing packages from ubuntu CD

Tags: apt

I'm having some problems installing packages off the cd. The ubuntu server is installed in a small local network with a dns but no internet connection. When I try installing a package, i.e. lamp or vsftpd it just tries to resolve the name of the update server. After some tries it gives up instead of checking the CD. I've added the CD using `sudo apt-cdrom add`. I've also tried using tasksel, which opens aptitude, without any luck.

How do I install packages (lamp, ssh, ftp, dhcp, samba) off the CD without internet connection?

EDIT:
Since this was unclear: We're given a server with ubuntu server installed and we're supposed to install lamp, ssh, ftp, dhcp and samba on it. To ensure we aren't cheating (asking the internet for help during the contest) we are limited to using only the cd.

Comment: It may just be that the "deb cdrom:" line is commented out.  See [How to install packages from server CD after installing the system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253630/how-to-install-packages-from-server-cd-after-installing-the-system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well help anyone who might have this problem.

The list of sources for apt to use is located in:
`/etc/apt/sources.list`

The first row is the cd, uncomment it by removing the leading hash. You can use nano to edit it like this:

`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Enter the password if prompted.

Also, comment away all internet sources if they aren't available, i.e. you are on a computer without internet connection. Just add hashes in front of all the other rows.

After that you just save the file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, and you're all good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try all these methods https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection

If you cannot use USB sticks either you are left with packages on CD. So please check that those packages you want to install are on CD! As space of the CD is limited I doubt that lamp is available from CD. Maybe you can get a DVD with more packages on it.

Comment: They're suggesting using another online computer and a usb stick to transfer files. However, I'm not allowed to use an internet connection at all. Their link to the official documentation is broken (404).

Comment: So your are stick to use only the packages on CD? BTW: you must have downloaded the CD from internet too, right?

Comment: I've got the cd, an installation of ubuntu server but no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this:
In bios my ISO USB STICK  was detected as "CD-ROM" i changed this value to

Interpret USB STICK AS "HARDDRIVE"

After that i booted from this stick and installed Ubuntu 16 LTS. Everything works