# How to install packages from server CD after installing the system

Tags: server, apt, package-management, software-installation, samba

I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 from CD onto a machine with no Internet connection.  Originally I did not select the Samba file server task during installation, but now I want to install it.  I have tried "sudo apt-get install samba" and "sudo apt-get install samba4" but the packages cannot be found.

I assume the necessary packages are on the CD.  Do I have to explicitly mount the CD?  If so, what should I mount it as?

I have found answers to questions about upgrading packages from the Internet, or installing lesser-used packages using apt-offline.  But that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: See this page for assistance: https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/installing-from-cd.html

Comment: @user300458: For the future, please try to refrain from editing a post just to add the correct tags, especially when the question already has an answer...  This creates unnecessary work for the reviewers...  Thank you!  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the step-by-step approach described in the link. You should be able to do it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

***Regarding the mounting related query***

When you mount a disc normally with the file browser (nautilus etc) it mounts disks by interacting with udisks behind the scenes.
You can do the same thing on the command line with the udisks tool. 
eg
/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sdb1
The bit after --mount is the device name of the partition you want to mount. (/dev/something)

Alternately try mounting the CD using the mount command.You can check the [MAN page for "mount"](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) if you are new to mount command.

Comment: The [linked page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) and a [related page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) have the solution.  It seems that the "deb cdrom:" line is commented out by default.  I uncommented it by removing a # and then executed `sudo apt-get update`.  It is not necessary to mount the CD; it is sufficient to put the CD in the drive.  Another useful command is `sudo tasksel` which reruns part of the character-mode GUI system install, and `sudo tasksel install samba-server` which installs the specific task.  Thanks.